# Bindings not updating inside datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a datagrid where I change a cell depending on what is chosen from the other column.

Let's say, my first column shows Weekdays (enums). If the user choose "Monday", the cell in the second column will be a TextBox. If the user chosoe a different day(eg. Friday), it'll become a Textblock with Text="Hooray!", else Textblock Text="".

Both Textbox and Textblock binds in the same property. But this binding does not work. Please help...

XAML

```
<DataGrid Margin="0,10,0,0"
                          x:Name="dataGrid"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding TheCollection}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding TheSelectedItemFromTheCollection}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Days"
                                                CanUserReorder="False"
                                                CanUserResize="False"
                                                CellTemplate="{StaticResource local.DataGridDays}" />
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value"
                                                CanUserReorder="False"
                                                CanUserResize="False"
                                                CellTemplate="{StaticResource local.DataGridValue}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<DataTemplate x:Key="local.DataGridValuesEditable">
    <StackPanel>
        <Border Background="White"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Padding="4">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding InitialValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                     Margin="0" />
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="local.DataGridValuesDefault">
    <StackPanel>
        <Border Background="White"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Height="30"
                Padding="4">
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding InitialValue, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                        Margin="0"
                        Width="55" />
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="local.DataGridValue">
    <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                        Value="{DynamicResource local.DataGridValuesDefault}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedDay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 Value="Monday">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                                Value="{DynamicResource local.DataGridValuesEditable}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<TheModel> _theCollection;

public ObservableCollection<TheModel> TheCollection
{
    get
    {
        if (_theCollection == null)
            _theCollection = new ObservableCollection<TheModel>();
        return _theCollection;
    }
    set
    {
        _theCollection = value;
    }
}

private TheModel _theSelectedItemFromTheCollection;

public TheModel TheSelectedItemFromTheCollection
{
    get
    {
        if (_theSelectedItemFromTheCollection == null)
            _theSelectedItemFromTheCollection = new TheModel();
        return _theSelectedItemFromTheCollection;
    }
    set
    {
        _theSelectedItemFromTheCollection = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TheSelectedItemFromTheCollection");
    }
}
```

Model

```
public string SelectedDay
{
    get { return day; }
    set
    {
        day = value;
        if (day == TheWeekDays.Friday.ToString())
        {
            InitialValue = "Hooray!!";
        }
        else
            InitialValue = string.Empty;        
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedDay");
    }
}

private string _initialValue;
public string InitialValue
{
    get { return _initialValue; }
    set
    {
        _initialValue = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("InitialValue");
    }
}

public IEnumerable<WeekDays> TheWeekDays
{
    get
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(WeekDays))
                    .Cast<WeekDays>();
    }
}
```

Comment: `{Binding InitialValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}` Can you possibly explain why you expect this to work?

Comment: At first, there's no RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}. But then I tried to put that and still its not working. What else do I need to change?

Comment: Look at the visual studio output window, it will display some error text for failed bindings. My guess: you need to set the `ContentControl.Content` property as `Content="{Binding}"`, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: And don't forget to remove the `RelativeSource`.

Comment: Here's what I did: I removed the RelativeSource, changed the  <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" into <Setter Property="Content". What happened is the control is not changing anymore. The former makes it change tho...

Comment: Seriously, you need to learn about bindings and ContentControls more in depth. You are just randomly changing details and sometimes something works, most of the time it doesn't. Your change doesn't make any sense and has nothing to do with the commented suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for the rant and judgment you gave me prior to answering the question I needed. Yes, I solved it now by placing <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ...> . I misunderstood what you said ContentControl.Content at first but then I realized what I did is just wrong. As for my knowledge regarding WPF, I am using it for 5mos now so I not quite an expert yet. Again, thanks for the help

Comment: PS, kindly make your comment as an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the desired situation:

The `DataContext` of `local.DataGridValuesDefault` and `local.DataGridValuesEditable` should be the row item `TheModel`.

With this `DataContext`, the bindings can be written as follows:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding InitialValue,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

and

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding InitialValue}"
```

The `DataContext` of `local.DataGridValue` contains the desired item. A `ContentControl` will turn its `Content` into the `DataContext` of its `ContentTemplate`, so the `Content` needs to be linked with the outer `DataContext`. Also, the trigger binding can be simplified:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="local.DataGridValue">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                        Value="{DynamicResource local.DataGridValuesDefault}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedDay}"
                                 Value="Monday">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                                Value="{DynamicResource local.DataGridValuesEditable}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</DataTemplate>
```